# I have an .exe file in Jfrog artifactory, how to use Go package manager to download that as a dependency using "go get" command

Tags: go, artifactory, go-get

I have configured GOPROXY with artifactory URI and trying to use go get command to download the exe file from the repository.
Sample:

1. `set GOPROXY=https://username:apikey@jfrog-artifactory.com/artifactory/go/virtual-go`
2. `go get com.temp/artifact/10.10.10.1/abc.exe`

> go get: module com.temp/artifact/10.10.10.1/abc.exe: reading https://username:apikey@jfrog-artifactory.com/artifactory/go/virtual-go/com.temp/artifact/10.10.10.1/abc.exe/@v/list: 404

Comment: `go get` is not about downloading _anything._ It's about downloading Go packages, and it's quite specific about what requests it performs and how it interprets their results. In other words, it's not a `curl` written in Go. You might start [there](https://go.dev/ref/mod#goproxy-protocol). As to fetching arbitrary artefact from JFrog—you'd better refer to its documentation, and I'd start with a plain call to `curl` or `wget`.